# How to modify google selected canonical URL when the URL is not valid anymore

Tags: web-crawlers, canonical-url, google-selected-canonical

I am the owner of two domains, domain1.com and domain2.com,

A canonical URL : domain2.com is selected by google for domain1.com while the url does not exist anymore, how to make Google re-select domain1.com as the valid url ?

Knowing that we can't ask for the indexing of a URL that doesn't exist, it's been more than 1 week that this is going on.

The Google bot has not passed on the domain2.com since May 14 (which at that time was valid)

For domain1.com the Google bot passed today (May 25) but the URL of domain2.com is still used as the url selected by Google.

I have also made a redirect from domain2.com to domain1.com 5 days ago

Answer (score 2):

If the site does not exist anymore then it will return a 404 and will be dropped. Google does not drop a 404 ASAP because sometimes sites are down and they return, so normally one must wait for google to be certain.

In your case it may not be as long as for most people because you got in before a core update. Google is cleaning up the SERPs as we speak.

But I would if you can, put a 301 redirect on the old domain during this update. If it is an E-A-T update, (Expertise, Authoritativeness, Trustworthiness), the links matter. And all the more so if the site is related to money or life, (IE financial, healthcare).

Google has not said its an E-A-T but some people may wish it to be, and are thinking out loud.

https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2022/05/may-2022-core-update